# How to change ApplicationBar fontfamily?

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I am developing windows phone 7 application. I need to change applicationBar font family. if anyone know the ans post here.

mycode:

```
 <shell:ApplicationBar BackgroundColor="#5a4d26" ForegroundColor="White" Opacity="0.9"  IsVisible="True" Mode="Minimized" IsMenuEnabled="True"  >
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="about us"  Click="PageClicked1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="subscribe" Click="PageClicked2"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="terms and conditions" Click="PageClicked3"/>                 
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="privacy policy" Click="PageClicked4"/>    
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the font for the menu items since the application bar is not a silverlight control.

Here are the best practices for application bars:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431813(v=vs.92).aspx